# detecting node.js http.get calls that take long time

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, profiling

A handler that makes multiple http calls to render a page takes a long time to return. I'd like to detect which of the calls take long time to complete. A profiling approach that I've found via googling[1]

1. doesn't work on Mac OSX
2. seems involved
3. displays way too detailed information for my needs

I'm using express and Q promises nested several layers deep if it makes any difference

[1] http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/

Comment: I suppose you could use the connect [responseTime](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/responseTime.html) middleware, and instead of adding a header, log the time taken if it was over x milliseconds. You'll be able to get the URL from the `request` argument.

Comment: If you made it an answer and include an example I'd make it an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Use middleware to track the requests and log them if they take too long.

An example would be:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var start = new Date;
    var maxDuration = 3000; //3 seconds
    var url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;

    if (res._responseTime) {
        return next();
    }
    res._responseTime = true;

    res.on('header', function() {
        var duration = new Date - start;
        if (duration > maxDuration) {
            //this request took longer than 3 seconds, log it.
            log('This request took longer than 3 seconds. URL: ' + url + ' Time: ' + duration + 'ms'); //Pseudo code
        }
    });

    next();
});
```